# Elastic Beanstalk の platform がやっていることは資料などにまとまっていますか?

Tags: aws, aws-elasticbeanstalk

Elastic Beanstalk を使うと、良い感じに web アプリケーションを、 aws のインフラにデプロイすることができます。その際、aws によって提供されている platform (例: Ruby + Puma) では、 rails のコードの実行に必要になるもろもろのミドルウェアなど(ruby, nginx, postgresql の dev package, etc, etc)は勝手にプラットフォームが用意してくれます。

Rails は、それ自身がいろいろ自動化していることもあり、 elastic beanstalk の環境にデプロイした際、なんだか動かないからデバッグ、みたいなことをわりとよく行ったりします。であるならば、この platform がどのような設定によって構成されているのか、つまりどうプロビジョニングされたのかが資料にまとまっていると、問題が起きたときのデバッグなどがやりやすくなるのではないか、と考えました。

## 質問

Elastic Beanstalk の各 platform について、それがサーバーに対してどのようなプロビジョニングを適用した結果になっているのかは、何かしら資料にまとまっていますか?

(イメージ、 docker でいう Dockerfile などがあると嬉しいと思っています。)

Comment: 参考: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history.html

Comment: こちらは、ざっくりと何のミドルウェアがどのバージョンでインストールされているか、の情報しか得られないと思っており、しかし、 middleware 以上に、 nginx <-> puma => の中の rails であったり、さらにはその際のとくに puma プロセスの bootstrap まわりで行っている処理など、そういった情報が、わりと、 rails を使っているとほしくなるなぁ。。と思っています。